# 3D visualization software for scientific molecular dynamics model

Tags: 3d, data-visualization

I am writing a program that will visualize a molecular dynamics experiment. The input will be a file with the location of each atom at each timestep. There will be ~100k atoms and ~500 timesteps. Atoms will be represented as spheres. Connections between atoms will be represented by cylinders.

Here are some requirements for the program (in order of importance):

1. ability to move, rotate, and zoom to change the image
2. ability to make a movie from the positions at various timesteps
3. ability to select an atom with the mouse
4. ability to create a GUI
5. ease of installation on Mac, Windows and Linux.

Can anyone recommend a language, visualization library or method to approach this? Any other thoughts would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to consider [ParaView](http://www.paraview.org); what you need to do is to save all relevant data in [VTK](http://www.vtk.org) format (the library has functions for that) and you're done. It has excellent post-processing capabilities (such as coloring, transparent particles, animations) and is well-tested.

If this does not seem enough flexible to you, I have some experience with `c++` lib [QGLViewer](http://libqglviewer.com) (don't get confused by the `.com`, it is free and cross-platform). You need to write OpenGL code for the particles by yourself, which is pretty easy.

That said, I know there are several "scene graph engines", which can help you greatly perhaps, but I think other would better comment on that, as I never used them.

FYI [this movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfQpnxDSbqQ) was done with Paraview (you find many more examples, for sure), while [stuff here](https://www.yade-dem.org/doc/tutorial-examples.html) is from OpenGL with QGLViewer.

Comment: +1 For ParaView reference. Note that there is also VisIt which does a similar job. Also, VisIt (I'm not sure if ParaView can do this) can automatically draw the bonds for you, see, for example, [here](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Molecular_data_features#The_Molecule_Plot)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think the spheres will be too overlapped for 100k atoms -- you will see only edges. So, I suggest to use a "bold" dots for atoms and lines for connections -- it will be much faster and allows to see more details.

Formally, [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net) (GPL plotting library) and its front-end [UDAV](http://udav.sf.net) satisfy all yours requirement. However, I'm not sure that it will be fast to draw 100k spheres and cylinders.