# Visualizing Molecular Dynamics Simulations in 3D

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, simulation, data-visualization

I've been working with some legacy C Molecular Dynamics code, and it came with it's own home-grown visualization routines.  I am wondering if there isn't something better and more flexible that I can use, since I am reaching the limitations of the current approach.

The current routines are all using OpenGL, and then drawn via X11 (I'm on a mac most of the time).  There is a problem related to this where I can display the simulations while they are running on linux, but capturing them returns a black screen.

My basic problems with this are that:

1. I don't have any experience with OpenGL or X11, or even graphics for that matter.
2. Adding in new objects to draw is *hard*.

So my options are to learn OpenGL and X11, and figure out what is going on, or try something else.  I do write out the information that the movies duplicate into a binary file as the sims run, and I can always read that in and create the movies later.

What I need is the ability to:

- Create various basic geometric objects in 3D
- Having the ability for them to change color based on orientation, etc, would be nice
- Be able to generate the movies in .mov format (I use ffmpeg on .bmp files right now)
- Be able to manipulate the perspective for either 3D (be able to rotate the image), or to be able to have multiple perspectives simultaneously (polar projection, side view, etc)

I see that some of this was covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541275/3d-visualization-software-for-scientific-molecular-dynamics-model), which I am going to take a look at, but I really want something that I could use real-time as the sims run to inspect what is going on for bugs, etc.

Comment: So what's your question?  What's the specific problem ?

Comment: Is there a visualization library for MD code that other people use, and can fulfill the abilities above?

Comment: I suggest you to clear your original question and ask it again based on your comment. Also, please search the web.I remember stumbling at least on 3 scientific visualization libs powered by OpenGL.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I will try the web search again - my problem was that it kept diverting me to physics engines, not data visualization libraries.  I will go looking again before I ask another question.

Comment: May I suggest considering Javascript as your frontend platfor mfor visualization? See also: http://tslmy.github.io/md.js/